# Why this event fires twice?

Tags: c#, winforms, onchange, devexpress-windows-ui

I can not figure this one out.

I have a windows form and a DevExpress LookupEdit on it.

The lookup edit has a databinding to property A of BindingSource BS on its editvalue.
The databind BS is attached to object C. C is a EF dabatase first object. Like this.

BS.DataSource = C

In the EditValueChanged event of the LookupEdit I want to change the value of another property of object C, like this:

```
private void lookUp_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            if (lookUp.EditValue != null)
            {
               C.B = NewValue;

            }
        }
```

What happens is that when I get to  "C.B = NewValue" EditValueChanged  fires again and prevents the values from changing. It fires because the Property changed of C fires.

What I'm doing wrong? How do I solve this?

Comment: Please avoid adding "thank you notes" and signature to your post. See [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) before adding them back.

Comment: do you anywhere in property C to alter the lookUp edit ?

Comment: looks like you have `ValueMember` of your `lookUpEdit` as `"B"`, of course its `DataSource` is `BS`?